# Bash: Update the parent variable from function variable

Tags: bash

i want to update the variable a become 2. But the result is always 1. Is there anyway to do it?

```
a=1
aple(){
        a=2
        echo "apel"
}
b=`aple`
echo $a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this call:

```
b=`aple`
```

Which invokes `aple` function in a subshell hence changes made in subshell are lost and not visible in the parent shell.

Call your function as:

```
aple
echo $a
2
```

---

As per your comments if you want to assign a value to `b` also then have your function as:

```
a=1
b=
aple() { a=2; b="apel"; }
```

Then call it as:

```
aple
echo "$b:$a"
apel:2
```

Comment: if i still want to use b=`apel`, is there anyway to update it?

Comment: `b=\`apel\`` will always create a sub shell hence changes will be lost in parent shell.